# PHP call from JavaScript function via AJAX to store data in mySQL(AMPPS localhost) just doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

After one whole day of trying various things I learned from other threads, I still can't get my code to work. I'm basically just trying to send data from a `JavaScript function` to a `localhost database` (server created using AMPPS).

Currently, I have a JavaScript file with the following function:

```
function WritetoDB() {
    alert('Reached. No problem getting here.');
    $.get("savedata.php");
}
```

I've also tried `$.post`, `$.ajax`, (with their appropriate parameters and such) but none of them seem to work either. Originally, the function was supposed to receive and pass on some variables that need to be stored on the database, but I'm trying to get it to work first before passing on any variables.

This is the 'savedata.php':

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mysql";
$databaseName = "database";
$tableName = "table";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

$A = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 'this is A');
$B = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 'this is B');
$C = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 'this is C');

$sql = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (columnA,columnB,columnC)
    VALUES ('$A', '$B', '$C')";

$conn->close();
```

I tried executing the `PHP` code in the `index.php` file and it works (data was sent to the database). However, it doesn't work when I'm trying to call it from a function in the `JavaScript` file. Most solutions from guides/forums I referred to seems to work for others, but not on mine.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't rely on the `real_escape_string()` functions to prevent SQL injection, [they alone are not sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string). You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: Just a question: You're using JQuery functionality. Have you included all the JQuery files correctly?

Comment: show code online

Comment: can you show your current code how you are send data to the php file ?

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to see if it is succeeding. If not what is the status?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware There are other functions that use jquery calls ($.ajax) and it works fine so I assume all the JQuery files are included correctly?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam The code to send data haven't been built yet as I'm still trying to get the PHP file to save the data ($A,$B,$C). For now, the function WritetoDB was successfully called as the alert was fired. Then, no matter what I tried, no data was saved to the database. I'm unsure if the PHP file was even executed or not.

Comment: does running the php file alone with some dummy / predefined values work correctly?, which i donot think so , i just added the fix for your code see if that helps you out @anon7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such conditions it is preferred that you try to run the `php` code standalone with some predefined / dummy values to check if it is working correctly or sending appropriate response that we need from it.

To troubleshoot your `php` file not saving data into the `database` first of all you need to do the following.

Remove syntax error on these line

```
$B = mysqli_real_escape_string(($conn, 'this is B'));
$C = mysqli_real_escape_string(($conn, 'this is C'));
```

because of extra parenthesis wrapped change them to

```
$B = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 'this is B');
$C = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 'this is C');
```

then you are not using the database parameter in you connection change the line

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

to

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$databaseName);
```

after that you need to `execute` this `query` which is the main thing in the insertion of the data into the database, which you are missing kindly add these line before the `$conn->close()`

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

see here for basic help on how to connect `php` and `mysql` database and insert data with `sql` query

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)